# Constrained variables in set-builder notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a set of variables $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ that are subject to upper bounds $X_i$ such that $x_i \leq X_i $ for each $ i \in \{1, 2, ..., n\}$. I want to write this in set-builder notation. I tried $\{x_i\ |\  x_i \leq X_i, i \in \{1, 2, ..., n\}\}$ but it does not seem right to include the $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$ set in the definition of the $x_i$'s. What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: A possible way to do this is: $\{ x_i | x_i \leq X_i, 1 \leq i \leq n \}$

Comment: I did not consider this option because I thought it wouldn't be explicit that $i$ is a positive integer rather than a real number.

Comment: Do you want to write a single subset or $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $n$ separate subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You can just add that restriction: $\{ x_i | x_i \leq X_i, 1\leq i \leq n, i \in \mathbb{N}\}$. You can leave $1 \leq$ out of the right side depending on whether you have 0 in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @RobPratt $n$ separate subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: If you want $n$ separate sets, the $i\in$ should not appear inside any of them.  The domain for $i$ should be expressed outside the definition of the $i$th set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways:
$$\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n \mid x_i \le X_i \quad \forall i\in\{1,\dots,n\}\}$$
$$\{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n \mid x_i \le X_i \quad \forall i\in\{1,\dots,n\}\}$$

Two more ways, using interval notation:
$$(-\infty,X_1] \times \dots \times (-\infty,X_n]$$
$$\times_{i=1}^n (-\infty,X_i]$$

Comment: Those formulations still contain the set $\{ 1, 2, \ldots, n \}$, which the OP wants to get rid of. And those ways result in different sets than in the original post (yours contains tuples, rather than just real numbers).

Comment: @hff The two sets I proposed are equal to each other, so either they both match what the OP wants or neither does.

Comment: Both are different from what OP wants. I think I edited my comment after you read it. Sorry, for that.

Comment: Yes, I was responding to your original comment.  I suspect the OP wants tuples but didn't know how to write them.

Comment: The tuple notation works too, but as @hff1 mentioned I suspected there would be a way to write it without putting a set into the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Using set-builder notation:
$$\{x_i\mid 1\le i\le n\,\text{ and }\, x_i\le X_i\}.$$

Combining set-builder notation and the listing method (so, a bit unorthodox): $$\{x_1,\ldots,x_i,\ldots,x_n\mid x_i\le X_i\}.$$